# how reach the unnamed object in python

Tags: python, class, object

```
#first way
class temp:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

object1 = temp("abolfazl")
print(object1)

#second way
class temp:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

print(temp("abolfazl"))
```

both do the same action(I guess :)), creating the instance of a temp class but if  we do in a second way we can't retreive that object or i guess so

could you please tell me what are the differences? and what did "self" do i thought it does something with "object1" in way one code but now I confused

Comment: You can't retrieve references to unnamed objects. Because if the instance isn't bound to anything it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Other than not being able to refer to the object again, there's no difference.

Comment: `self` refers to the current object instance. So, yes, for `object1`, `self` refers to `object1`. As for your other question about what the difference is when you don't save a reference to the object - it will get created and run through its `__init__` code, but once that's done, the Python garbage collector will clear the object out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Objects have a reference count; when the reference count reaches 0, the object is destroyed.

In your first example, `object1 = temp("...")` creates the object and sets its reference count to 1: `object1` is that reference. When you pass it to `print`, it temporarily has a reference count of two, as the `print` parameter the object is bound to is a second reference. Once `print` returns, the parameter goes out of scope and the reference count is decremented back to 1.

In your second example, the *only* reference to the `temp` instance is the parameter in `print`. When `print` returns, the reference count drops from 1 to 0, and the object is destroyed.

`self` is just the parameter bound to the new instance for the duration of the call to `temp.__init__`.